# Error running example Reapp project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm just trying to get going setting up my first [Reapp](https://reapp.io/) project, but failing at the first hurdle.  I get a blank screen with console error of 404 main.js not found.

Here's the errors I'm getting when I do `reapp run -d`:

```
Building with Webpack...
Webpack server on http://localhost:3011
Hash: e779570c713250e7b167
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 823ms
  Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
main.js  21.6 kB       0       main
chunk    {0} main.js (main) 52 bytes [rendered]
    [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built] [3 errors]

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack-dev-server/client' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kitchen-sink-master
 @ multi main

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kitchen-sink-master
 @ multi main

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-loader' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/kitchen-sink-master
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

This question is very similar: [Reapp error running sample Kitchen sink app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768260/reapp-error-running-sample-kitchen-sink-app)

So I tried the suggested `npm install` in the project, which gives me the node_modules folder, but gives me the following errors:

```
npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-dom@0.14.3 requires a peer of react@^0.14.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-tap-event-plugin@0.1.8 requires a peer of fbjs@^0.2.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID reapp-ui@0.12.70 requires a peer of react@0.14.x but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON reapp-kitchen@1.0.1 No license field.
```

I've gone on the react website to install some more bits with `npm install --save react react-dom babelify babel-preset-react` to no avail and am now stuck!

I think it might be something to do with my react version, but I can't figure out how to find what version I'm on.

- npm version: 3.4.1
- webpack version: 1.12.9
- reapp version: 0.8.28
- react version: unknown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is essentially that the GitHub project is broken, so it's not just my environment... I was doing everything correctly.

---

<s>Issue on this error listed here: https://github.com/reapp/reapp/issues/104</s>

**Edit:** The above issue link is no longer valid, instead there is a notice on the project https://github.com/reapp/reapp:

*NOTICE: Needs contributors, current broken, don't open a ticket open a PR [http://www.reapp.io](http://www.reapp.io_)*

---

The owner of reapp is no longer working on it to instead work on other projects.

I ended up using http://touchstonejs.io/ instead.

Comment: OOC, TouchstoneJS has no documentation. Does it need to have documentation, or should I just know React better and everything else makes sense?

Comment: @Trip The example is quite good, so I guess they intended users to copy and paste from that, there's not too much to it, I'd think of it like using bootstrap with classes you can use.  The project ended up being a bust, so that's the extent of my knowledge I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to get the reapp project running. You will want to install

1. react@0.13.2
2. reapp-ui@0.12.54
3. reapp-kit@1.2.15

in your project directory. Please refer to the following Github tickets.

- [issue4](https://github.com/reapp/starter-default/issues/4)
- [issue 5](https://github.com/reapp/starter-default/issues/5)